# Will this all fit together?

Tags: crankset

[Shimano BB-UN100 Square Taper Bottom Bracket 68/122 BSA Sealed Cartridge BB](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/310733783065)
[image: from ebay link]

[Sram / Truvativ PressFit BB30 /PF30 to BSA Bottom Bracket Adapter](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Shimano-BB-UN100-Square-Taper-Bottom-Bracket-68-122-BSA-Sealed-Cartridge-BB-/142305949426?epid=1165742698&hash=item21221876f2:g:IhQAAOSwTM5YwEBk)
[image: From ebay link]

And maybe I need something else?
Please help! Ordered once the wrong parts don't want to do it again

Comment: Yes the adapter fits the cartridge bottom bracket, but a useful answer cannot really be given without knowing what you are trying to do with them. What frame do you have and what cranks do you want to install? If you have a frame that takes modern BB30 bottom bracket bearing, it's strange to want to fit a much older style square taper crank.

Comment: and does the bracket goes with these cranks? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/371235012044?var=640367234511

Comment: I don't see anything in the description of that crank that says what length spindle it is designed for. The BB you linked to is 122mm spindle with 47.5mm chainline. You need to find a crank that matches that or figure out the correct numbers for that crank and find a bb to match it.

Comment: You should probably edit this to include the specific parts under consideration -- ebay links can go down. Also, that doesn't look like SRAM's BB30->standard adapter.

Comment: You may be better off reworking your question by telling us what frame you have and what you want to  build it into (or what you are trying to rebuild) and ask what bottom bracket and crank components would be most suitable, and how to make sure you get the spacing of the chain from the frame center line ('chainline') correct.

Comment: Vote to close as the question as it stands is either a shopping Q or we don't know what problem the OP is trying to solve. (Answering questions is easy, answering the right question - now that's hard)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Probably it will fit together fine.  But will it fit your bike?

The adaptor sleeve says

> This tough Nylon adapter is designed to be pressed into a PressFit BB30 (PF30) bottom bracket Shell and will then allow you to fit a normal Threaded style bottom bracket. So you could use a normal GXP style chainset or Shimano Hollowtech or other brands.  This bottom bracket adapter is to fit PressFit BB30 (PF30) frames which are 46mm internal diameter. (NOT normal BB30 which is 42mm)

And the cartridge BB is a standard looking 68mm english threadded unit, with an overall width of 122mm (probably for a triple front crank?)

So if your bike frame takes a Press Fit BB30 then this will press into the frame fine.  You will need a press tool to get it installed right though.

Whether the resulting chainline matches whatever your bike needs, that's another question.  Also, your cranks and chainrings will need to have a conventional square taper mounting.  If you have anything else, this won't work and you'd need to replace the cranks as well.

The cranks listed in your comment will fit the square taper interface, but they're single chainring and I'd be surprised if 122mm is the correct width.  If you still have the old BB axle, measure it for overall length.  Use calipers if possible, millimetres count.

Comment: Aside - why not buy a PF30 bottom bracket and get it press-fitted to your frame, as it was designed to have?  Why all this mucking about with adaptors?